# Pamldap connection refused

Tags: ssh, authentication, pam, ldap

I am trying to set up the ssh access through pamldap in Ubuntu 16.04 and after having everything configured I am not able to synchronize the /etc/passwd with the information of LDAP server.

ldapsearch works fine, so the binding options are well configured.

When I do

`getent group`

I can see all the groups of LDAP server, but

`getent passwd`

Only has the local users information.

By debugging nslcd I can see that it is able to find my user in LDAP server whenever I try to do a login (su or ssh) with a ldap user.

Additionally:
`su ldap_user`
Returns:

> No passwd entry for user

And when I try a ssh connection, the auth.log writes:

```
Invalid user ldap_user from IP
input_userauth_request: invalid user ldap_user [preauth]
pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=IP
pam_sss(sshd:auth): Request to sssd failed. Connection refused
pam_ldap(sshd:auth): Authentication failure; user=ldap_user
Failed password for invalid user ldap_user from IP port 55911 ssh2
```

`nsswitch.conf` file has:

```
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
# If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
# `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

passwd:         compat ldap
group:          compat ldap
shadow:         compat ldap
gshadow:        files

hosts:          files dns ldap
networks:       files ldap

protocols:      db files ldap
services:       db files ldap
ethers:         db files ldap
rpc:            db files ldap

netgroup:       nis ldap
sudoers:        files
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No LDAP user had the ObjectClass "PosixAccount", so the attribute uid was not being taken into account because the default class that was being used had no such attribute, which is mandatory to be able to login in Linux machines.